# C# - Gtk.ComboBox Does Not Contain a Definition for 'NewText'

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gtk#

I'm writing a C# Gtk# application under Mono/MonoDevelop in Linux Mint 17. I have a ComboBox on a form with 3 items in it. I was able to place it and such fine however, I get an error in the designer code stating that the ComboBox doesn't contain a definition for 'NewText'. The Mono documentation at docs.go-mono.com says that this NewText method is how you add items, however, apparently mine doesn't have it.

- My MonoDevelop version is 4.0.12
- The projects target Gtk# version is 3.0
  I have the following references and their versions referenced in the project

[image: References]

And finally, the designer code

```
//top of file declaration
private global::Gtk.ComboBox framestyle_Val;
//further down, this defines all the items
this.framestyle_Val = global::Gtk.ComboBox.NewText ();
        this.framestyle_Val.AppendText (global::Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString ("Single Sprite"));
        this.framestyle_Val.AppendText (global::Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString ("Left/Right Sprites"));
        this.framestyle_Val.AppendText (global::Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString ("Left/Right/Upside-Down Sprites"));
```

It's worth noting that apparently there's no AppendText definition/method either but I assume that'll be straightened out once we get this one straightened out.

Any ideas? I'm confused myself. Thanks in advanced,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. MonoDevelop seems to be unable to generate proper code to use with Gtk#3.

You may want to install Gtk#2, this will not override the GTK#3 installation, and target your project with this version to be able to use MonoDevelop's visual design abilities. 
And maybe you will need to create the clean GTK#2 project once again.

If you have found a solution to use GTK3, please give me an idea.

Comment: Proceeded to try Gtk#2 under Windows after seeing this and you were right. Thank you. I tried playing around to get it working under Gtk3 but I couldn't really figure it out